# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called for sarima

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, time-series, valueerror

this is the code and above mentioned is the error i am getting how to solve it and sarima_forecast is a series.

`Sarima_df = pd.DataFrame(sarima_forecast[0], columns = df.columns)`

Comment: Show us what is `sarima_forecast`

Comment: ````sarima_forecast = model_Sarima.forecast(len(test_final))```` where model_sarima is ````import statsmodels.api as sm
model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df, order = (1, 0, 3), seasonal_order = (3, 0, 3, 6),enforce_stationarity = False,enforce_invertibility = False)
model_Sarima = model.fit()
print(model_Sarima.summary())````  and test_final has each month dates from 2010 to2020

Comment: print it out and show me

Comment: 2001-01-01    152.863328
2001-02-01    153.483624
2001-03-01    156.240883
2001-04-01    151.401819
2001-05-01    147.004454
Freq: MS, Name: predicted_mean, dtype: float64 this is the sarima_forecast  values

Comment: Just try: `Sarima_df = pd.DataFrame(sarima_forecast, columns = df.columns)`

Comment: Tried but its not showing any values table is blank

Comment: `Sarima_df = sarima_forecast.rename(columns=dict(zip(sarima_forecast.columns, df.columns)))`

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns' i am getting attributeError for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `to_frame`:

```
Sarima_df = sarima_forecast.to_frame(df.columns[0])
```